# DataGrid doesn't show nested classes

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want my DataGrid in WPF show nested classes into my objects. I'm using NHibernate to retrieve data.

My Model class:

```
public class PublishedBook
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual YearSemester BookYearSemester { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Title, BookYearSemester);
    }
}
public class YearSemester 
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

My Repository class:

```
public class PublishedBookRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public PublishedBookRepository(ISession objCurrentSession) :
        base(objCurrentSession) { }

    public IEnumerable<PublishedBook> GetAllPublishedBooks()
    {
        return base.CurrentSession
            .CreateCriteria<PublishedBook>()
            .List<PublishedBook>();
    }
}
```

My XAML Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dagtagridPublishedBooks" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="YearSemester" Binding="{Binding YearSemester}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the second column, the data isn't displayed. 
Anyone knows why?
Thanks, guys!!

Answer (score 1):

The path for the binding on the second column should be the property name: `BookYearSemester`, not the class name `YearSemester`. Try:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dagtagridPublishedBooks" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="YearSemester" Binding="{Binding BookYearSemester}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jelly, but it also doesn't work. The ToString() value of the BookYearSemester property isn't displayed on DataGrid. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Because `YearSemester` is a class, you can show its properties either using full path for binding like `BookYearSemester.ID` or `BookYearSemester.Description`, or define custom template by using `DataTemplate` that will be replaced for class objects